# One element in attribute table not updating QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis

When I use attribute table with option "Show Selected Features", and there is only one object selected, when I change values, they stay the same (table is still showing values before change) unless I unselect and select again the same object.
There is no problem when 2 features are selected (when I change value, the new value is showing immediately in table).

Is there any option to change that in QGIS 2.18?